# Creating a 100K records in Account salesforce object using apex code

Tags: apex, create-records, bulk, dml-operations

I am trying to create an 100K Account records in my salesforce org using apex code in developer console, I managed to create till 1000 by this apex code.

```
List<Account> list1 = new List<Account>();
integer RECORD_COUNT = 1000;
for(Integer i = 0; i < RECORD_COUNT; i++){
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.name = ‘newAcc’+string.valueOf(i);
    list1.add(acc);
}
insert list1;
```

but the problem that this will let me create up to 10K records and not more.
So I am looking for a way to use bulk trigger in apex code that will allow me to create a 100K records in Account salesforce object.

Many thanks.

Comment: Well, you could make use of a class that implements the `Queueable` interface to insert some of the records, then chain another queueable (repeating until you have no more records to insert), but I think you're putting the cart before the horse here. _Why_ do you need this many records? What exactly are you trying to do with them? Chances are very good that you don't need nearly as many records.

Comment: Why not just use Data Loader?

Comment: Thanks for responding David,
I need a test script that tests the limitation of a production sandbox of creating a 100K records. So I don't wanna do any manual things like using dataloader which is I need an automated test script that will test the limitation.

Answer (score 4):

You can consider using a [Queueable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) apex.  You can chain, until final condition is met:

```
public class AccountCreator implements Queueable {
    private Integer accountsCreated;
    private Integer chunkSize;
    private Integer recordsCount;

    public AccountCreator(Integer chunkSize, Integer recordsCount) {
        this.accountsCreated = 0;
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
        this.recordsCount = recordsCount;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        create();
        chainJob();
    }
    
    private void create(){
        List<Account> toInsert = new List<Account>();
        Integer chunkCount = 0;
        //create new account until chunkCount less than chunk size, and total number of created accounts less than recordCount
        while(accountsCreated < recordsCount && chunkCount < chunkSize){
            Account acc = new Account(
                Name = 'newAcc' + accountsCreated
            );
            toInsert.add(acc);
            ++chunkCount;
        }
        insert toInsert;
        accountsCreated += toInsert.size();
    }

    //if accounts still need to be created, run another round
    private void chainJob(){
        if(accountsCreated < recordsCount){
            System.enqueueJob(this);
        }
    }
}
```

use this code from dev console, for example

```
AccountCreator creator = new AccountCreator(1000, 100000);
System.enqueueJob(creator);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Oleksandr, this script helped but, unfortunately by using it it only creates up to 4k records and sometimes less than that, and also an "Maximum stack depth has been reached" ERROR was shown.